# Google Maps под Android построение маршрута

Tags: android, google-maps

Можно ли из своего приложения построить маршрут в Google Maps не прибегая к запросу маршрута через REST API Google и последующему рисованию точек?

Другими словами нужно построить маршрут для автомобиля (допустим это будет доставка груза), но с использованием только Android приложения карт. Можно ли это как-то сделать через `Intent`?

Comment: А для чего, если не секрет? я чет суть уловить не могу. Типо нужно только расчет времени и дистанции?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: @iFr0z, спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Рад был помочь! Вот только хочу предупредить о том, что люди могут удалить гугл карты) и будет краш, поэтому и используют рест апи, дабы не было привязанности к другим приложениям, но в любом случае решать вам:)

Comment: Удалить могут. Только перед отправкой интента можно проверить наличие нужного приложения и тем самым предотвратить краш.В любом случае ещё раз спасибо за информацию!